# Is there any way to set the default font to 16pts in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, fonts, iterm2

I am going through several fonts such as “Consolas” and “Source Code Pro” and noticed in [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) there is no way to set default size to 16pts. Only 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 13pt, 14pt, 18pt, 24pt,... are available. What happened to 15pt, 16pt, 17pt?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also add custom values for font sizes. From the Font window, click the gear in the upper left, and choose "Edit Sizes".

[image: box with gear]

Then, enter your value.

[image: size edit field]

Comment: Doesn't this just duplicate Maletor's answer?

Comment: Didn't see that one - I've found images to be a little more useful when scanning a page with multiple answers.

Comment: @JustinW. It definitely did. Thank you for posting this.

Comment: how do I open the font window

Comment: @AeroWindwalker Open preferences (top menu), click "Profiles", select the "Text" tab, then click "Change Font"

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You can click on the number below the 'Size' column and write any value.

[image]

Comment: Mine is just a drop down with set font sizes, I can't type my own.

Comment: CodeCrack, by default the box to type your own size does not show up. You have to resize that window for it to appear.

Answer (score 4):

Open 'Preferences', click on the 'Profiles' tab, further click on the 'Text' sub-tab,

[image: Preferences]

and select the font and size:
[image: Profiles]

Comment: I prefer this solution for my use case which is slightly different from OP's. I wanted to increase font size on iterm2 only, and the size that I had wanted was already present as an available size

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but a brief review of iTerm's source code suggests your font preferences are stored in a property list named `DefaultBookmark.plist`, under the keys `Normal Font` and `Non Ascii Font`. The default values both being `Monaco 12`, if you were to change it to `Consolas 16` or `Source Code Pro 16` it should do what you want. You should be able to find these files with the command `find / -name DefaultBookmark.plist`, and since the name "Default" suggests there may be other property lists, you can find them with `grep -R "Normal Font" /` or `grep -R "Non Ascii Font" /`

Please keep in mind that it seems to occasionally ignore the font size and come up with it's own as it has a class called `FontSizeEstimator` which has [the following in its comments](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/c698bc4cad68ef46a6c44dc1d864390ec5f3c3bd/sources/FontSizeEstimator.m)

Lines 11 - 12:

```
**  Description: Attempts to measure font metrics because the OS's metrics
**    are sometimes unreliable.
```

Lines 65 - 68:

```
size.width = advances[0];
size.width *= [aFont pointSize];
size.width /= CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(cgfont);
size.width = round(size.width);
```

Although it seems as if this is only used for estimating the size of the window, rather than the size of the font being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

> Change the font sizes available in the Fonts window.
>
> 1. In an app such as Mail or TextEdit, choose Format > Show Fonts, or Format > Font > Show Fonts.
> 2. In the Fonts window, click the Action pop-up menu (cog), choose Edit Sizes, then do any of the following.
>
>    - Add a font size: Type a new size, then click the Add button +.
>    - Change the values on the slider: Type new values in the Max. and Min. fields.
>    - Remove a font size: Select it in the list, then click the Remove button -.
>    - Restore the original values: Click Reset Sizes.
> 3. Click Done.

Source https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21568?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) in particular the section about quoting (which I've fixed for you).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the preference file with the following commands:

`cd ~/Library/Preferences/
open com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`

Then use `cmd+f` to search `Normal Font` and `Non Ascii Font`, change the font size value from 14 to 16. Close the window and restart iTerm. Done:)

Just notice that the `plist` file is opened by **Xcode**, you may need to install Xcode to edit the plist file.